# Information_Schema function() exec history

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I would like to retrieve the 1 month history of accessed user functions on a postgresql database.

Where would I be able to look ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, no record of function calls is kept.

If you have `log_statement = all` you can get some idea from the system logs (especially in `csv` mode) but that won't show calls via other functions, etc.